# How does one actually disagree when reviewing an item?

Tags: support, flagging

When performing review tasks an option appears saying, "Flag or disagree..." but no option to disagree exists.  For example if a question has been flagged as "not an answer" or "very low quality" I think I ought to be able to say, "No, I think it's fine as is." That's how I interpret the intent of the "disagree" option anyway.  However, clicking on the pop-up results in only "flag" options being presented, so I have to cancel out and wander away- or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Good point. I've probably "disagreed" dozens of times by now, but I still always think the way the option is worded is weird, and takes time to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble actually finding this button (possibly due to the fact that I'm a mod), so I can't verify it for you, but buried in the middle of the flag options, there should be one for disagreeing. It's not the ideal place for it, but it should be there; if it isn't, let me know how you're getting to this dialog and I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Thanks.  I swear I read through all those options, but there it is  staring me in my sheepish-looking face.

Comment: @Jim - maybe you can tell me, because I didn't see it either.

Comment: Look for the flag type "invalid flags". That is the one to use.

Comment: I think my confusion comes from seeing "*I am **flagging** this answer because*"  But I don't want to flag it, I want **"unflag"** it.   Also, I have to read "it has invalid flags" several times to glean its meaning.  Especially on ELU, saying, "it has invalid flags" means that the flags which are part of the question's inherent attributes are invalid.  Instead, this option ought to read:  "It has been flagged in error (or erroneously)"